# ASP.NET change image path to https

Tags: asp.net

I have code which produces an image path. The issue is my site has been changed to https and the image no longer show because the image path is http. Can anyone suggest how I change the code below to https?

```
If routes.ContainsKey(m_id) Then
            Dim m_uri As Uri = CurrentNode.Uri
      Dim m_builder As New UriBuilder (m_uri.Scheme,m_uri.Host)
            m_builder.Path=String.Format("/resources/image/gritroutes/gritmaps/{0}.jpg",m_id)
            TitleBar.Text = Property_title + " for " + routes.item(m_id) + " - Council"
            phGritPic.Text = String.Format("<img src='{0}' alt='grit route' style='max-width: 530px;' class='auto' />",m_builder.ToString)
            phGrittingKeyText.Visible = True
        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change m_url.Scheme to m_uri.SchemeHttps

```
If routes.ContainsKey(m_id) Then
            Dim m_uri As Uri = CurrentNode.Uri
      Dim m_builder As New UriBuilder (m_uri.SchemeHttps,m_uri.Host)
            m_builder.Path=String.Format("/resources/image/gritroutes/gritmaps/{0}.jpg",m_id)
            TitleBar.Text = Property_title + " for " + routes.item(m_id) + " - Council"
            phGritPic.Text = String.Format("<img src='{0}' alt='grit route' style='max-width: 530px;' class='auto' />",m_builder.ToString)
            phGrittingKeyText.Visible = True
        End If
```